# Unity AR game not compatible with my device when uploaded on play store, but works when built locally

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, arcore

I have a AR game which works on my device when built locally
, but when I upload it to google play console for testing it is not compatible with my device.

It says only 624 devices are supported in device catalogue
I am using ARcore in unity engine

Then minimum api is set to 24 and highest for target api

Regard,
Krishna

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me once because I had put `Required` in my ARCore settings for Depth API. This setting is only for playstore afaik, and not when building directly. So it will hide the app for all phones with no Depth API support.

[image: Screenshot Project Settings]

Comment: Even after making depth as optional, most of the devices are not supported in Google Play console. But when I enable android manifest in publishing setting and optional depth in arcore, it is showing supported for 1000 devices